# Executing a script in a child directory from the current directory using windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have directory with this structure:

```
C:\MyDirectory\mychild1\mychild2\build.bat
```

I would like to execute the script `build.dat` from the `mychild1` directory without having to go to the `mychild2` directory. I tried this:

```
C:\MyDirectory\mychild1> \mychild2\build.bat
```

but it did not work. How can I do it?

Comment: remove the first backslash. It means "search at the root level of the current drive", so it is the same as `C:\mychild2\build.bat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\MyDirectory\mychild1> mychild2\build.bat
```